# Change color of a label in the barChart (TeeChart)

Tags: .net, xamarin.ios, teechart

I have a simpele bar chart with 4 labels. I want the 3rd label to be WHITE and have a BOLD interface.

I tried to access the Axis.Labels.Items and manipulate these, but the collection seems to be containing no elements. The event GetAxisDrawElement gives me the label but I have no access on the font and color properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the GetAxisLabel event, e.g.

```
private void InitializeChart()
{
  Bar series = new Bar(tChart1.Chart);
  series.Add(1);
  series.Add(2);
  series.Add(3);
  series.Add(4);

  tChart1.GetAxisLabel += tChart1_GetAxisLabel;
}

void tChart1_GetAxisLabel(object sender, GetAxisLabelEventArgs e)
{
  Axis axis = sender as Axis;

  if(axis.Equals(tChart1.Axes.Bottom))
  {
    axis.Labels.Font.Bold = e.LabelText.Equals("3");
    axis.Labels.Font.Color = e.LabelText.Equals("3") ? Color.Red : Color.Black;
    axis.Labels.Font.Size = e.LabelText.Equals("3") ? 16 : 8;
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I do the same for the MARKS. I also want to change the MARK's label and font. GetSeriesMark event gives you something, but I cannot change the font in this event. The .Items list is also 0.

Comment: A very similar technique can be used:    void series_GetSeriesMark(Series series, GetSeriesMarkEventArgs e)
    {
      series.Marks.Font.Bold = e.MarkText.Equals("4");
      series.Marks.Font.Color = e.MarkText.Equals("4") ? Color.Red : Color.Black;
      series.Marks.Font.Size = e.MarkText.Equals("4") ? 16 : 8;
    }

Comment: Thanks! Better to use the e.ValueIndex to check for the index.